# Dynamic paths for setValue using smart #keypath in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I realize the whole point of smart keypaths in Swift 4 (https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md) is to provide compile-time static type checking but my currently application utilizes keypaths that are composed dynamically at run-time.

This still works on non-Linux platforms:

```
open func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKeyPath keyPath: String)
```

However, it does not work on Linux, and besides if possible I'd like to switch over to using smart paths.

Is there a work-around to use smart keypaths in cases where you do not know the path in advance, and instead want to compose it dynamically like the old-style functionality?  Or, can you suggest how to refactor an old-style approach to use compile time paths?